# scala-maven-plugin my scala plugin fails to compile the code into java 11

Tags: java-11, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to move my project to JDK11 and Hadoop3.
but however hard I am trying , the compiler is compiling the .class file into Java8 .. ( major version 52).

What am I missing ?

Here is the shorter maven target run output for the scala plugin just to compile the scala files.

```
userabcd@17722-p-mac app_segment-manager-jobs % mvn scala:compile -DdisplayCmd=true -DrecompileMode=all           

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----< com.appnexus.data-management-platform:segment-manager-jobs >-----
[INFO] Building segment-manager-jobs 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.33 has been relocated to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33: MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:4.8.1:compile (default-cli) @ segment-manager-jobs ---
[WARNING] The artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.33 has been relocated to com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33: MySQL Connector/J artifacts moved to reverse-DNS compliant Maven 2+ coordinates.
[INFO] /Users/userabcd/dev/codebase/DATA-MANAGEMENT-PLATFORM/app_segment-manager-jobs/src/main/java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/userabcd/dev/codebase/DATA-MANAGEMENT-PLATFORM/app_segment-manager-jobs/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 154 source files to /Users/userabcd/dev/codebase/DATA-MANAGEMENT-PLATFORM/app_segment-manager-jobs/target/classes at 1706197129486
[INFO] cmd:  /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.21/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.9.0/jna-5.9.0.jar:/Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/org/jline/jline/3.21.0/jline-3.21.0.jar:/Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.13.8/scala-compiler-2.13.8.jar:/Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.8/scala-library-2.13.8.jar:/Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.8/scala-reflect-2.13.8.jar -classpath /Users/userabcd/.m2/repository/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/4.8.1/scala-maven-plugin-4.8.1.jar scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile scala.tools.nsc.Main /private/var/folders/wz/t670kvlx70bfjw12cvn9jv2w0000gn/T/scala-maven-8193362676990251360.args
[WARNING] warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
[WARNING] 1 warning
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0.0 s
[INFO] compile in 10.2 s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.585 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-25T21:08:59+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my pom.xml

```
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <spark.scala.version>2.13</spark.scala.version>
    <scala.version>2.13.8</scala.version>
```

.
.
.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <addJavacArgs>--release 11</addJavacArgs>
                <addJavacArgs>-target 11</addJavacArgs>
                <addJavacArgs>-verbose</addJavacArgs>
                <displayCmd>true</displayCmd>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```